# How to get product name,image,short description when add new prodduct & edit product in admin using event

Tags: magento-1.9, product

I want to send email when admin add new product or update product having product name, image & short description. Can you know new product or updated product?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the event `catalog_product_save_after`.
You will receive in your observer as parameter the product instance.

Something like this:

```
public function sendProductEmail($observer)
{
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    $name = $product->getName();
    $shortDescription = $product->getShortDescription();
    if ($product->getImage()) {
        $imageUrl = $product->getImageUrl();
    } else {
        $imageUrl = null;
    }
    //send mail here.
}
```

Comment: When product image is not present then shows Image file was not found error how to check image present or not.

Comment: I think it will show you the placeholder image, but see my edit

Comment: Can i check invertory qty & stock availability when admin add new product?